# How To Open A File Using Text Edit In Terminal in MacOS

Tags: shell, vim, terminal, zsh, nano

Another small question. I just recently migrated to ZSH and, so far I am loving it! My question is how can I open a file using TextEdit so that I can edit it using a GUI? Make no mistake, Vim is an amazing command-line tool for editing files in the terminal along with nano.

Let's say that I wanted to open the .zshrc using vim :

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

In the same way, open the .zshrc using nano:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

How can I open the same `~/.zshrc` file using text edit through the terminal?

Thanks a lot and I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the solution, I know it's a bit tedious but, you can open the `~/.zshrc` using this command :

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: what about setting an alias? like `alias textedit="open -a TextEdit"`?

Answer (score 3):

The `open` utility has an option `-e` that opens the file in TextEdit (essentially a shorthand command).

```
open -e ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Text Editor (gedit) is the default GUI text editor in the Ubuntu operating system.
To open a specific file: `gedit filename`
To open multiple files: `gedit file1 file2`
[Here's More Information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit)

Comment: that is the solution for ubuntu, not macOS ;)

Comment: @KushalPandya : The question is not about `gedit`. `TextEdit` is the name of the program the OP wants to use.